# replace small numbers in Perl

Tags: perl, numbers

In a text file, I have many lines looking like `(a,b,c)` where a, b, and c are double precision real numbers, for instance `(8.27605704077856,0.505526531790625,1.15577754382534e-05)`. Is there a simple way to replace numbers smaller than 10e-4 by 0 in Perl?

**Edit:** For instance, the text file to be treated looks like:

```
\plotinstruction[color,style,width]
points{
(8.27,0.5,1.1e-05)
(8.26,1,4.1e-06)
(8.25,1.5,3e-06)
}
```

and I want to write in a new file:

```
\plotinstruction[color,style,width]
points{
(8.27,0.5,0)
(8.26,1,0)
(8.25,1.5,0)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but perhaps use of [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) would help?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @values = (8.27605704077856, 0.505526531790625, 1.15577754382534e-05);
my @filtered_values = map(($_ > 1e-4) ? $_ : 0, @values);

print Dumper \@filtered_values;
```

Results:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '8.27605704077856',
          '0.505526531790625',
          0
        ];
```

To parse input, you could use a regular expression to extract a comma-separated string of numbers, using `split` on that to get a Perl list to run `map` upon.

Comment: thanks, it looks promising but not all the lines are a set of three numbers so it should first test if the line start with `(`. Right now your code (almost) fails.

Comment: You didn't provide an example of input, so I just gave you a general idea of how to use `map`. How you parse the input is up to you -- you could easily parse your input into a list of `values` and run `map` on that.

Comment: yes, sorry, I edited my question to be more precise. I'll have a look at the `split` command together with your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
perl -pwe 's/\d[\d.e+-]+/$& < 0.001 && $& > -0.001 ? "0" : $&/ge' < INPUT > OUTPUT
```

(`-p` means to read in the input, one line at a time, into `$_`, run the program, print out `$_`, and loop again; `-w` enables warnings; `-e` means that the program is specified directly as a command-line argument; `s///` is a regex-substitution; `/g` means that it's a "global" substitution; and `/e` means that the replacement-text should be treated as a full Perl expression, rather than as a string with mere variable interpolation.)